# Will deleting a request after accepting it lower opinion?

Tags: the-escapists

I understand that in The Escapists, denying a request/mission lowers the inmate's opinion of you. However, if a request is accepted and then deleted in the Journal, I have no clue if it effects their opinion or not. I often accept then delete requests I don't want to do so that it doesn't lower their opinion, but I have never actually kept track of their opinion bar while doing so. No thumbs down icon appears over their heads upon deleting requests but I'm still not sure. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it will lower opinion a lot. (The exact numbers may differ slightly between versions, but when you cancel a favor from the journal, it will lower opinion a lot more than if you say "No" in the first place.)

The following information was verified in The Escapists `version 1.37` on Steam.

- Saying "Maybe" to a favor does nothing
- Saying "No" to a favor will lower opinion (-5)
- Saying "Yes", but later canceling from the journal will lower opinion a lot (-15)

---

*(Reportedly, in some early versions of the game, cancelling a favor was buggy. If you said "Yes" to a task for `Aaron` that involved taking an item from `Zeke`, canceling from the journal should have lowered opinion for `Aaron`, but actually lowered opinion for `Zeke`. This is no longer a problem in the current version of the game.)*

https://steamcommunity.com/app/298630/discussions/0/35222218796843647/

---

There is more information about how to raise or lower opinion on the following page:

http://theescapists.wikia.com/wiki/Stats